# Step by step guide for asa 5505

Tags: cisco, configuration, cisco-asa

Is there any step by step guide for configuring an ASA 5505 out there? Most of the info that i keep running into are repost of the same article. The most useful guide i found so far was this one. http://www.firewall.cx/ftopic-7053-days0-orderasc-0.html

Answer (score 6):

As Martijn already said, your focus should be less on the ASA and more on the IOS itself. The ASA is just a stepped down piece of hardware that is running <strike>the same IOS that the monster ASAs are running</strike> a very similar IOS to the monster ASAs. See the comments below for clarification. As for learning the IOS, there's plenty of good books out there. How about the [Cisco IOS In a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008694) book form O'Reilly?

You may want to check out the [Accidental Administrator's guide to the Cisco ASA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449596622).

You also have the option of using the Cisco ASDM. [Here's the user guide for it](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asdm/6_1/user/guide/asdmug.pdf).

Unfortunately, there's not going to be a terribly helpful "cheat sheet" out there. Learning the ASA 5505 (really, learning the IOS) is going to take lots and lots of thick books or long PDFs and web pages.

Comment: ASA doesn't run IOS.  It is a similar OS, with many shared commands, but it isn't the same OS.  Admitted good knowledge of IOS and Cisco networking will be useful, but there is more with the ASAs.

Comment: While ASAs run PIXOS, not IOS, it's pretty darn close to the same thing for most things; learning about the OS is going to be much more beneficial than some "spoon fed" guide though.

Answer (score 2):

A step-by-step guide will be hard to find, since a Cisco ASA is such a versatile device.

I would suggest upgrading the firmware to version 8.2, which is the version most books and guides seem to cover. You'll also need to upgrade the ASDM software to match with the firmware. ASDM is now the recommended way of configuring the ASA. It also has some guides and help built in.

I also found [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cisco-ASA-All---one-Networking/dp/1587058197/) useful as a reference guide.